# Node.js web request to external server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a nodejs project, and I've found something that I can't afford. 
In a single moment, my nodejs application needs to ask something to another webserver. This web is a javascript application. It receives an string and answers with another string.

How can I implement this in nodejs, or which modules do I need.

The schema is something like this

Nodejs --------> http://"webserver"/app.html?var=string

```
^                                      |
|_______________string2________________|
```

Comment: Isn't this just a normal Node HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

you can issue HTTP requests by this package - https://www.npmjs.org/package/request
or without it -
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know package request.

Comment: So, thanks for the answers. I didn't know this package. I'm trying but it don't works. Maybe my syntax is not ok.

I want to store in var "respuesta" the answer of the javascript.

So, thanks for the answers. I didn't know this package. I'm trying but it don't works. Maybe my syntax is not ok.

I want to store in var "respuesta" the answer of the javascript.



    var url = "http://mydomain?question=";
     url += string1;
    respuesta = request(url);


Thanks for everything!


Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a request using the [HTTP module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) or use the [Request Package](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to simplify things (Available using [NPM](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-request)). Since these methods use callbacks like everything else in Node.js, you can easily carry on handling new incoming requests and only reply to that specific request once you received a response from the remote server.

Comment: I think i'm doing something wrong, because, when I execute it, it download the document (same as I use wget), instead of requesting the answer. For example, if I do:
`code` request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}}
I expect not to download source code. Just the respones, as if my nodejs app were a "browser"

Comment: There is definitely something that you are not understanding around this. If you `wget` then you are doing a request to the server and the document you receive back is the server's response. If you are not getting the response you expect (Like the document instead of an answer), you are either requesting the wrong thing, or the server is not programmed correctly. Either way, you will need to post a lot more detail in your question if you want to get help on that.

Comment: Ok, there was a problem from my side, because javascript is calling a function included in a flash objet, so nodejs could not execute this. I've posted another question, if anybody know how can I resolve this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044881/how-can-i-execute-a-function-included-in-a-flash-object-from-server